# hostname for BackConnectionHostNames sharepoint 2010 regedit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, host-header, windows-server-2008-r2

Environment details - Windows Server 2008R2 and SharePoint 2010
The users are facing repeated login prompts issue when trying to open any SharePoint site.

All internet explorer settings are in place. Nothing changed.

So, I followed this step -

```
Start--> Run --> regedit --> HKEY_Local_Machine`--> System --> CurrentControlSet --> Control --> LSA --> MSV1_0
```

Right Click --> New --> Multi-String Value

Give a name BackConnectionHostNames

**But I dont know whats the correct hostname/site name/host-header that i should enter in BackConnectionHostNames box (by right click - modify).**

My site urls are as follows -

http://servnm:port1/pages/default.aspx
http://servnm:port2/pro1/sites/pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

BackConnectionHostNames only pertains to users who are accessing SharePoint from the server itself.  Assuming your users are not logging directly onto the server to access SharePoint, you have some other sort of misconfiguration on your web app.

Comment: In ULS log i see this error - "An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9979999. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time alloted to this operation may have been a portion of longer timeout.."

Comment: But my **securitytokenservice.svc** web page displays this message - "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."